# How to render an xml generated by xopus using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml structure that goes like this

```
<root>
    <element>
        <Heading>
            This is the Header
        </Heading>
        <Content>
            &lt;Region&gt;
                &lt;Section&gt;
                    &lt;Paragraph&gt;
                        The last two lines define the end of the template and the end of the style sheet.
                &lt;/Paragraph&gt;
                &lt;/Section&gt;
            &lt;/Region&gt;
        </Content>
    </elememt>
</root>
```

Now I have to render this as html using xsl. The heading is pretty straight forward. But the hard part is the content. I get the output as the text surrounded by tags like this

### This is the Header

```
<Region><Section><Paragraph>The last two lines define the end of the template and the end of the style sheet.</Paragraph></Section></Region>
```

How do I solve this? I absolutely have no idea. Any help is welcome. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: the content has been quoted, so the easiest thing to do is pass the content of `<Content>` to an xml parser and then process the result, xslt 3 (will) have an xml parse function as standard but most xslt processors have an extension function that could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **XSLT 3.0** solution that uses **[`parse-xml-fragment()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="3.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element/Content"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Content">
     <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml-fragment(.)" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An **XSLT 2.0** solution that uses **[`xsl:character-map`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" use-character-maps="angle-brackets" indent="yes" />

<xsl:character-map name="angle-brackets">
    <xsl:output-character character="&lt;" string="&lt;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string="&gt;"/>
</xsl:character-map>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element/Content"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Content">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An **XSLT 1.0** solution that uses **[`disable-output-escaping`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#disable-output-escaping)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element/Content"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Content">
     <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```